# How to Change Columns position in an Object array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects, and I want to change the columns order and add a static value for each one of them
from this:

```
 var homes = [
        {
            "h_id": "3",
            "city": "Dallas",
            "state": "TX",
            "zip": "75201",
            "price": "162500"

        }, {
            "h_id": "4",
            "city": "Bevery Hills",
            "state": "CA",
            "zip": "90210",
            "price": "319250"
        },...
    ];
```

to this:

```
 var homes = [
        {
            "h_id": "3",
            "price": "162500",
            "zip": "75201",
            "city": "Dallas",
            "state": "TX",
            "staticValue":  "1234"
        }, {
            "h_id": "4",
            "price": "319250",
            "zip": "90210",
            "city": "Bevery Hills",
            "state": "CA",
            "staticValue":  "1234"
        },...
    ];
```

I have tried this:

```
let data = homes.map(function(x) {
                                  return {h_id:x.h_id,
                                         price : x.price,
                                         zip : x.zip,
                                         city : x.city,
                                         state : x.state,
                                         staticValue : "1234"}
                                   });
```

but the columns order are still

```
h_id,city,state,zip,price,staticValue
```

instead of:

```
h_id,price,zip,city,state,staticValue
```

what am I doing wrong?

**Edit**

Actually, I'm using this Reorder for sending the object as a DataTable to a C# controller. and when arriving at the Controller, it is Ordered as I wanted. so apparently the map function I used worked fine.

here's a working example:
[jsfiddle.net/a6o8jbh9/1](http://jsfiddle.net/a6o8jbh9/1)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do that

> object is an unordered set of name/value pairs

If you really want to stick with order then go for array instead of objects.

The ordering of object properties is non-standard in ECMAScript also.

And I dont have any idea about what is the reason for reordering the objects?, you can simply access them by property name. So what is the benefit are you looking from reordering ?

since `ES2015` there are methods that are based on specific rules defining the order of properties, and apart from one particular case the order is chronological. The order of properties in an object depends on the type of the included properties and their values. So we can guaranty the order

We can take an example with `map` function

```
var homes = [
        {
        "1abc": "162500",
            "h_id": "3",
            "city": "Dallas",
            "state": "TX",
            "zip": "75201"


        }, {
            "h_id": "4",
            "city": "Bevery Hills",
            "state": "CA",
            "zip": "90210",
            "1abc": "319250"
        }
    ];
let data = homes.map(function(x) {
                                  return {h_id:x.h_id,
                                         '1abc':x["1abc"],
                                         zip : x.zip,
                                         city : x.city,
                                         state : x.state,
                                         staticValue : "1234"}
                                   });
console.log(homes)

console.log(data)
```

The output will be like

[image]

[image]

In output the order got changed. Based on `ES2015` the property order is based on  specific rules, so we cannot guaranty the reorder works perfectly in all cases, it might work in few cases(If our input match with the rules defined) but not in all cases.

Note : As per your comment I believe that you need to send this object to a controller action and from there you will call a merge query. If this is the scenario I think the `Json` object order doesn't matter. Your `c# model binder` has the capability to bind it with the `controller object.` If your controller is written correctly and if it is calling the `SP` with right param order then no worries. If your controller logic is wrong then we cannot event solve this issue by changing the Json property order.

Comment: the reason was sending this object as a table to a C# Controller that I cannot edit.
The controller sends the table to a merge Stored procedure in SQL Server which needs to be the exact order of columns.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and information,
 but In my case, the map function worked

Comment: @DorLugasi can you provide me a jsfiddle for your working example

Comment: The result is not shown in Javascript, it is shown in the c# controller.
when changing the order with the map function, the order changes too in the DataTable

Comment: @DorLugasi but the code you have written/or the accepted answer is in js right ? I was asking for a jsfiddle on the same.

Comment: @DorLugasi not this one , i mean the working code that Jackbashford provided, that code seems not working  from my side . that why asking for jsfiddle for checking

Comment: you are right. it is not working, I didn't check and I thought it was the same concept 
but my code is working fine.

Comment: @DorLugasi I thought like the code you have accepted is working for u, I have checked the same and it doesn't seems to working for me so i got confused. In fact in satckoverflow if you are accepting an answer then it should work for u. ok thanks for the response.

Comment: @DorLugasi You cannot guaranty the order in your code also check this fiddle open each object and check the order https://jsfiddle.net/uk89a6e3/

Comment: i do not understand your addition, https://prnt.sc/mkwigy ,  everything looks fine in the second table

Comment: and I'm am talking about an API controller, not a MVC controller. so, no models are included, just a function that receives a DataTable

Comment: @DorLugasi  whether its api controller or mvc controller doesn't matter. And I dont know without a parameter how you are going to send data to controller action ? Query string ?

Comment: @DorLugasi U said just a function  thats receives DataTable , I believe you are calling your api controller from your client side and passign these data am i tight ? If yes how u r sending data to the  api action ? Post , get what u r using ? s objects array , string in what format u r sending ?

Comment: I'm sending it with a post HTTP request

Comment: @DorLugasi Using ajax ? Then the data part will be  a collection right ? homes  collection basically your array of objects. So your api method should have a param(mostly type of  your class)

Answer (score 1):

You need to access the correct properties and reorder correctly - ES6 provides useful features for doing this:

```
let data = vm.homes.map({ h_id, city, state, zip, price } => { h_id, price, zip, city, state, staticValue:"1234" });
```

Comment: Can you please provide me a fiddle for the same

Comment: @DorLugasi This is the way to do it, it sometimes may not work because of the ideas outlined in ArunprasanthKV's answer. You may need JSON methods.

Comment: please provide a jsfiddle with your example. because when i tried it , it does not work